# How to split a string into two bits after so many characters PHP?

Tags: php, string, file

I am looking for a very efficient way of splitting a string and returning both parts.

The string I need to split is 893,004 characters long, each line in the string is 163 characters long, and I want to split it after 100 lines.

A quick representation of the string file that is gotten from a file using regex,

```
'/[a-z0-9]{40}/i' '/[a-z0-9]{40}/i' '/[a-z0-9]{40}/i' '/[a-z0-9]{40}/i' // 163 characters
'/[a-z0-9]{40}/i' '/[a-z0-9]{40}/i' '/[a-z0-9]{40}/i' '/[a-z0-9]{40}/i' // 163 characters
'/[a-z0-9]{40}/i' '/[a-z0-9]{40}/i' '/[a-z0-9]{40}/i' '/[a-z0-9]{40}/i' // 163 characters
```

And so on and on lol,

My attempt at splitting the string after 100 lines,

```
// FILE CONTENTS
$content = file_get_contents($file);
// GET PARSER GXDE
$split = preg_split('/^[a-z0-9\s]{16300}$/i', $content, 1); // REGEX DOESNT WORK
var_dump($split[0]);
```

I am just looking to split the string after 100 lines in the file how is this easily done?

Comment: You could check the last error with [`preg_last_error`](http://nl3.php.net/preg_last_error), I assume some limit is reached. Regexes arent't the most efficient way to go here afaik. Treffynnon's advice seems apt.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to deal with a big file in chunks: why not [**split**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split) the file into many files of 100 lines?

Answer (score 3):

I would just use [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to get the file lines as an array or [`fgets()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) to extract the file line by line. This would then allow you to use a simple counter to break the file at the appropriate number of lines.

Comment: Yes I thought of this but sometimes the file can be over 1.5million lines I don't really want to iterate over it that much, and I need to extract the first part for data and rewrite the other part back over the original file, if that makes sense

Comment: Whether doing it by regex or by fgets, in both cases the whole file will have to be read, examined, written, etc. You cannot 'rewrite part of a file'. So, other then personal preference, any other reason you don't want to 'iterate over it that much'?

Comment: Never thought of it like that guess I am just trying to over think things again lol!

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using a regex if you don't have to. A regex is a relatively expensive operation and if you're using a regex to get a fixed-length string that's just a waste of processing.

It's not clear what you mean by "split the string after 100 lines". This adapted example from [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) will write out the file in 100 line chunks (if all lines are 163 chars including the newline).

```
$handle = @fopen("/inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    $i = 0;
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 163000)) !== false) {
        $i++;
        file_put_contents("chunk$i.txt", $buffer);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```